# How to insert comparison records results between 2 tables into another table?

Tags: mysql, database, insert, compare

status_tb

```
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
| id | status   | description | state_id |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |     new  | north       | 1        |
|  2 |   assign | south       | 2        |
|  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        |
|  4 |    Fixed | west        | 3        |
| 35 |     Test | South-test  | 4        |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
```

status_backup_tb

```
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|backup_id | id | status   | description | state_id |
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1       |  1 |new       | north       | 1        |
|  2       |  2 |assign    | south       | 2        |
|  3       |  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        |
|  4       |  4 | Fixed    | west        | 3        |
|  7       |  35| Rejected | Testing     | 4        |
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Once I get my input result from the resulting mysql, I need to **insert** those results to another table(audit_status_tb) like below...
How do I achieve it?

Here the sql to get my required records

```
(SELECT 
s.id, 
'status' AS Column_changed, 
s.status AS Old_value, 
b.status AS New_value 
FROM status_tb AS s
JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
ON b.id = s.id AND 
   b.status <> s.status)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT 
s.id, 
'description' AS Column_changed, 
s.description AS Old_value, 
b.description AS New_value 
 FROM status_tb AS s
 JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
ON b.id = s.id AND 
   b.description <> s.description)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
s.id, 
'state_id' AS Column_changed, 
s.state_id AS Old_value, 
b.state_id AS New_value 
FROM status_tb AS s
JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
ON b.id = s.id AND 
  b.state_id <> s.state_id)
```

audit_status_tb

```
|new_id | id |Column_changed| Old_value   |New_value |
+-------+----+--------------+-------------+----------+
|1      | 35 | status       | Test        | Rejected |
|2      | 35 |description   | South-test  | Testing  |  
+-------+----+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

Im not sure about what kind of insert-select? mysql I should used to retrieve those values and input them in the above format...

Comment: Is new_id a primary key auto increment in audit_status_tb ?

Comment: yes, I just need to insert as from id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`Insert Into .. Select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement:

```
INSERT INTO audit_status_tb (id, Column_changed, Old_value, New_value) 

SELECT 
  s.id, 
  'status' AS Column_changed, 
  s.status AS Old_value, 
  b.status AS New_value 
FROM status_tb AS s
JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
  ON b.id = s.id AND 
     b.status <> s.status

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
  s.id, 
  'description' AS Column_changed, 
  s.description AS Old_value, 
  b.description AS New_value 
FROM status_tb AS s
JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
  ON b.id = s.id AND 
     b.description <> s.description

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  s.id, 
  'state_id' AS Column_changed, 
  s.state_id AS Old_value, 
  b.state_id AS New_value 
FROM status_tb AS s
JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
  ON b.id = s.id AND 
  b.state_id <> s.state_id
```

Comment: thanks that what I try yesterday but wasnt sure where to properly put the select statement for the insert

Comment: @EmanulaSohn my query should work. Let me know if you are facing any syntax errors ?

Comment: Error, Im getting duplicate if I re-execute the query. I should not have any duplicate results in the `audit_status_tb` table.Help pls By duplicate I mean, same `id, state_id, status , description` rows in some cases...

Comment: @EmanulaSohn it will obviously reenter the same data. One way is to put a composite unique constraint on `(id, Column_changed, old_value, new_value)`

Comment: how do I add this composite unique constraint? I try adding `WHERE s.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM audit_status_tb)` at the end of each select statement and its seems to work...What do you think?

Comment: @EmanulaSohn where clause would also work. As a safety you can add unique constraint also: `alter table audit_status_db ADD unique (id, column_changed, old_value, new_value)`

Comment: If i add the unique constraint, I cant get duplicate id, etc... I just do not want any 2 rows that are Completely Similar... Meaning I do not want row 2 to be completely similar to row 3 (excluding the auto_increment id)...

Comment: @EmanulaSohn that is why a composite index is needed. It will be a single constraint covering all column into one.